# How to create a sensor from scratch

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a sensor package for a custom made sensor.

Is there any tutorial on how to create such a package?
The sensor is a ring of IR transmitter and receiver.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164156/how-to-create-a-sensor-from-scratch/) by [Quadrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8696/quadrobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-14**:
Do you want to know how to create a package (like coding the package) or how to add it to the ROS packages ?

**Comment by [Quadrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8696/quadrobo/) on 2014-05-14**:
I would like to create a sensor like these examples: http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors

After creating it, I would be implementing it on the robot that I have.

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-03-25**:
As I don't want to post a link for an answer, I will just put this here.

[Tutorial for Custom Sensor Module Design](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/Tutorials/custom_sensor_design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[The first page of Tutorial for Ros...](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

There is everything you need there...

- Creating a ROS Package
- Building  a ROS Package
- Understanding ROS Topics

When you don't know something, try searching on the wiki first, there is a lot of information there.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Quadrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8696/quadrobo/) on 2014-05-15**:
What I meant in my question is the philosophy behind creating such a driver/package for the sensor. i.e. where do the authors start from? I have done the tutorials before.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-15**:
Ups sorry I misunderstood your question...

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-03-25**:
This does not answer the question at all. THe Question clearly emphasizes sensor packages. Should not be marked as the correct answer